# ReadProcessMemory from host to Hyper-V Windows Guest VM

Tags: memory, virtual-machines, virtual-memory, hypervisor

Is it possible to use [ReadProcessMemory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) or some other form of it maybe via a library to read memory from a virtual machine running inside Hyper-V?

The host is running Windows 11 the Guest is running Windows 10 through Hyper-V

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. In all likelihood the answer is no. But I'd love to see an answer to this one. However, I think even from kernel mode this one may be tough. I don't think from usermode (e.g. with `ReadProcessMemory`) you even stand a chance.